# Problem with git proxy work only few minutes after reboot of windows

Tags: windows, git, proxy

I have some problem with git proxy on my company' laptop.

I added environment variables HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and a FTP_PROXY in system variables.

After reboot my git works fine for some minutes everything is fine - push work and I can pull everything.

But after few minutes of laptop working I face error:

`Push failed unable to access 'https://gitlab.****.com/**/**/': Proxy CONNECT aborted`

I do not know what to do I have already tried to unset git config variables as http.proxy, https.proxy but it does change nothing.

When I face this error I perform computer reboot and I am able to push or pull and the error message does not appear[ but only for just a few minutes !].

System: Windows
VPN: turned ON

Git reinstall does not help.

The error occurs in cmd and in PyCharm.

Git user.name and user.email are correct.

I also tried to use http.proxy and https.proxy as http://login:pwd@server:port and it does change nothing.

Please help me, thanks and best regards.

Comment: Is there any antivirus in your machine ??

Comment: Well there is no external antivirus on this machine, probably only Windows Defender @RafsanJany

Comment: Have you tried with SSH key ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

- reinstall git
- set credential.helper to manager-core in ../Git/etc/gitconfig
- set environment variables to small letters ftp_proxy, http_proxy, https_proxy and use the same 'http://' prefix for each of them
- remove all windows credentials with git: prefix,
- remove http.proxy from git config --global -l, --system and --local
- add windows credential ( generic) for https://gitlab.domain.com

If did not work reinstall windows and try once again.